# Angular Material : alternative of $mdMedia('gt-md') in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to add a sidenav to my web-application and I want it to be responsive , I'm using Angular Material2 and Angular 4
`<md-sidenav #sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left"  md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')" hide-gt-md opened="true">`

the "md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')"" doesn't seem to do its job here and i wonder if it is deprecated or has an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're mixing Material 1.x with Material 2.

Here is an example of how Material 2 works:

```
<app>
  <md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav align="left" opened="true">Drawer content</md-sidenav>
    <div class="my-content">Main content</div>
  </md-sidenav-container>
</app>
```

Check out the [most recent docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) to make sure you have the right format. Note: In the API calls @Input means you set the item in the DOM (like align, and opened).

Comment: thank you for your attention , is there a solution to make the side-nav responsive to the size of the browser window , that is to hide it when minimized to a certain X

Comment: Are you talking about display width size? This feature hasn't been implemented yet, but there is an open issue with several working examples you can work from here:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1130 (angularexample's post about halfway down looks like the best method in my opinion)

Comment: I solved the problem with this :  <md-sidenav #xxxMenu (window:resize)="$event.target.innerWidth<769?xxxMenu.close():xxxMenu.open()">  ,thank youu

Answer (score -1):

that is a conflict between angular material 1 and 2 i just knew it, i'm sorry but i can't help you